# Put a span tag inside specific WooCommerce checkout field wrapper html tag

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I'm trying to put a `<span>` tag inside of the `<p>` wrapper tag on checkout page for shipping city field. I have tried so much different ways, but all of them have failed.

Here is my code attempt (doesn't work):

```
function hackies( $field, $key, $args, $value ) {

// Wrap all fields except first and last name.
if ( $key === 'shipping_city' ) {
    $field .= '<span>hello world</span>';
}

return $field;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_form_field_text', 'hackies', 10, 4);
```

But it's not working, anyone could help with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using the right hook and the right way. Using PHP `str_replace()` function in a hooked function using `woocommerce_form_field` filter hook do the job:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_form_field', 'hackies', 10, 4);
function hackies( $field, $key, $args, $value ) {
    // Wrap all fields except first and last name.
    if ( $key === 'shipping_city' ) {
        $field = str_replace( array('<label ', '</span>'), array('<span class="special"><label ', '</span></span>'), $field );
    }
    return $field;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> This works for "input text" fields type… It requires something a bit different for other fields types.